# Conditional forward filling string values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a column which is a reflection of the current state of an object in a data frame that contains a timeline of actions performed on this object.
I have columns reflecting `add` and `remove` actions and would like to create a new column reflecting the content that is currently available.

**Example**: Given the DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(1, None, None, None),(2, None, 'Apple', None),(3, None, 'Banana', None),(4, None, None, 'Apple'),(5, None, None, 'Banana'),(6, None, None, None)],
    columns=['day', 'inventory', 'bought', 'sold'])
print(df)
```

```
   day inventory  bought    sold
0    1      None    None    None
1    2      None   Apple    None
2    3      None  Banana    None
3    4      None    None   Apple
4    5      None    None  Banana
5    6      None    None    None
```

I would like to populate the `inventory` column like so:

```
   day      inventory  bought    sold
0    1           None    None    None
1    2           None   Apple    None
2    3          Apple  Banana    None
3    4  Apple, Banana    None   Apple
4    5         Banana    None  Banana
5    6           None    None    None
```

Comment: What if you buy an Apple and already have one, then sell one?

Comment: You'd still have one apple. This is just an example for the problem I have. Items would be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you buy/sell unique items, you can use a list comprehension with `set` operations:

```
S = set()

df['inventory'] = [','.join(S:=S.union([b] if pd.notna(b) else set())
                                .difference([s] if pd.notna(s) else set()))
                   for b, s in zip(df['bought'].shift(), df['sold'].shift())]
```

*NB. this requires python ≥ 3.8 due to the walrus operator (`:=`).*

output:

```
   day     inventory  bought    sold
0    1                  None    None
1    2                 Apple    None
2    3         Apple  Banana    None
3    4  Apple,Banana    None   Apple
4    5        Banana    None  Banana
5    6                  None    None
```

##### python < 3.8: using a function

```
def inventory(df):
    S = set()
    out = []
    for b, s in zip(df['bought'].shift(), df['sold'].shift()):
        S = (S.union([b] if pd.notna(b) else set())
              .difference([s] if pd.notna(s) else set())
            )
        out.append(', '.join(S))
    return out

df['inventory'] = inventory(df)
```

Comment: To me its better to use a method than using all the set operations in this case.

Comment: @SomeDude you can still a function if you want with the dataframe as parameter, the issue with `apply` is speed

Comment: I was talking about speed only. Do you think this method is faster than the apply in my answer? I think apply doesn't need to be slower always.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the walrus operator available as the python version that I'm forced to use is <3.8. Any way of re-structuring?

Comment: Then you can write a function that does the same with a variable instead is the in place walrus.

Comment: Check the update

Comment: Thanks for the addition, works nicely and fast!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method:

```
inv = []
def update_inventory(x):
    if x['bought'] is not None:
        inv.append(x['bought'])
    if x['sold'] is not None:
        inv.remove(x['sold'])
    return ','.join(inv) if inv else None
df['inventory'] = df.apply(update_inventory, axis=1).shift().replace({np.nan:None})
```

print(df):

```
   day     inventory  bought    sold
0    1          None    None    None
1    2          None   Apple    None
2    3         Apple  Banana    None
3    4  Apple,Banana    None   Apple
4    5        Banana    None  Banana
5    6          None    None    None
```